# Pass json data angular2 routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to pass a json object from one component to another while routing.

I guess it can be achieved using service but I like to know whether it can be done using routing itself.

The data property like below which is available while defining the route can be helpful but I need to pass the data from component code, I mean not static data

```
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can but you have to use JSON.stringify and convert the object to route parameters and pass them as part of the route.

Comment: doing so will make them visible in url. right ? as long the parameters are few it's fine but in my case I don't want it to visible in url

Comment: Right, they will be visible in the URL. The service is your only other option with some kind of model that can save states between components.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in other answer, it is not possible to pass an object through routing without the object being stringified, which means that the object would be visible in the URL. One way to avoid using a service and that your object would be visible in URL is to your **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**. Before routing you would set the object in `localStorage` and after routing fetch the object from the `localStorage`, so first something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(theObject));
```

Then I would make a function in the service for getting the item after routing:

```
getMyObject() {
  return JSON.parse.getItem('myObject');
}
```

And after navigation just call that function:

```
this.myObject = this.myService.getMyObject();
```

Hope this is a viable solution for you! :)

Comment: The object is still visible but in console is there another way?